# What are the best apps for kids out there

Tags: apps

I have two small kids and I am always looking for good apps for 2-4 year olds. My favorite ones so far are the Sesame Street book applications and Color Sprouts. Can you recommend something?

Comment: Hey, Filip! This is a pretty subjective question, since different kids like different things (not to mention the tastes and beliefs of their parents!) You *might* bring up the topic [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3223/windows-phone) though, if you're interested in discussing it with others.

Comment: @Shog9: I think that answers for this could be very useful to people and I am looking for apps like this myself.  Why can't this be reopened as a wiki, like this question? http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/46/157

Answer (score 1):

There's a great interactive story based on "The Princess and the Pea" called [The real princess](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/apps/dd75c731-729e-e011-986b-78e7d1fa76f8).  My 7 year old daughter loves it.  It's free if you get the ad supported version.